OpenMP GPU offloading vector iterator
I have this working test code, which maps std::vector for offloading and checks if the calculation is correct:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int vec_size = 3;
    std::vector<double> vec_data{std::vector(vec_size, 2.0)};
    for (auto &it : vec_data)
    {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }

    double *data = vec_data.data();

    auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

#pragma omp target data map(tofrom : data[ : vec_data.size()])
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (int it = 0; it < vec_size; ++it)
    {
        data[it] = data[it] + data[it];
    }

    auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "GPU: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>>(endTime - startTime).count() << " ms ; " << std::endl;
    for (auto &it : vec_data)
    {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}

and I would like to write the for cycle using iterators, something like:
for (auto it = vec_dat.begin(); it != vec_dat.end(); ++it)
        {
            *it = *it + *it;
        }

but I can not figure out the right syntax. Can you help me with it? Or is it even possible to have iterators on GPU?

it = it + it; does not seems a valid iteration loop, especially with it != data.end(). Neither on CPU nor any device. I guess you mean *it = *it + *it;. By the way, did you check the device is actually used in your initial test code? This is quite frequent for the target implementation to silently use the CPU when it should not. Besides high_resolution_clock is rather a bad clock despite the name. You should use a steady clock for the wall clock time. Still, If you measure a very short time, the benchmark will be biased anyway whatever the chosen clock.

Last but not least, be aware that desktop/notebook GPUs are really not designed for double precision computations. Some even do not support that and will report an error (e.g. Intel GPUs) while others will just be painfully slow (Nvidia and AMD client-side GPUs) -- slower than an optimized CPU code. Expensive server-side GPUs should be used for double precisions and such servers sometimes provide a different OpenMP implementation which behave differently.

The "something like" was written without much thinking just for you to have an idea what I meant. I corrected it.
Thanks for mentioning the double precision issue, I'll take a look at it and prepare some test calculations. I am aware of the speed tradeoff, this is why I experiment with other implementations of parallel computing too and measure the time. This is just part of my test code (minimal example), where I also test the CPU on much bigger vectors and multiple times. I test on GTX3060 BTW.

Ok. Note you can get performance information about this GPU here. It reach ~20 TFlops in simple precision but only 0.2 TFlops in double precision. Most CPU can do better. For example, my i5-9600KF of 2019 can reach 0.4 TFlops. That being said, the memory throughput is generally better on GPU (though the PCIe transfer is very slow and always slower than the host memory so this specific operation will always be slower on GPU than on CPU with multiple cores).

Regarding the iterator, it is supported for basic OpenMP for loops and I do not see any restriction regarding devices in the specification. Which kind of compiler do you use and compiler version? It might just be a limitation of your current compiler. PS: for the previous comment it is 12 TFlops for SP (I wrongly read the field of the 3070 but it does not change much).

@JérômeRichard Again, the difference in FLOP/s between float and double is only relevant for compute bound algorithms (mostly GEMM). With memory-bandwidth-bound algorithms like this the bad FLOP/s should be hidden behind the memory latency (Latency hiding is what GPU's are good at). Naturally double also needs double the memory bandwidth and therefore half the performance compared to float here but that is the case anyway.

@paleonix I mentioned memory throughput this time, and also mentioned that this operation is PCIe-bound anyway so always slower on GPU ;) .

@JérômeRichard That is assuming that the data isn't already present on the GPU or the results needed on the GPU in the actual application. So yes another weakness with this benchmark is that it is measuring transfers and compute without being able to disambiguate between them. Offloading a single bandwidth-bound computation with transfers will be worse than using the CPU even if you use the beefiest server GPU. Bringing up FLOP/s with the given code just seems misleading to me even if the information itself is accurate.
